# Represent file directory-type structure in graphql

Tags: graphql

Say I have a file directory structure:

```
├── folder_a
│    └── folder_b
│         └── file_x
├── file_y
```

Is this possible to represent in a `graphql` query?

```
query FileTree {
     ?
}
```